# What's wrong with this stored procedure SQL command?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add this stored procedure into a MYSQL database and it keeps giving me error. The error message from MySQL (MariaDB) is not clear enough to tell me what's wrong with my query. I checked the query on http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ and it said that the query syntax is correct. I have no idea what's causing the error. Can you guys figure out what's wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tigrenoble.postBook (
IN seller VARCHAR(7),
IN bookid INT,
IN bookcondition VARCHAR(10),
IN bookprice NUMERIC,
IN posttype CHAR,
IN postdate DATE,
IN bookdescription TEXT,
IN bookquantity INT
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tigrenoble.Post
(seller_dce, book_isbn, book_condition, book_price, post_date, book_description, post_type, book_quantity,post_status)
VALUES
(seller, bookid, bookcondition, bookprice, postdate, bookdescription, posttype, bookquantity,'A');
END;
```

MariaDB says:

```
MariaDB [tigrenoble]> CREATE PROCEDURE tigrenoble.postBook (
-> IN seller VARCHAR(7),
-> IN bookid INT,
-> IN bookcondition VARCHAR(10),
-> IN bookprice NUMERIC,
-> IN posttype CHAR,
-> IN postdate DATE,
-> IN bookdescription TEXT,
-> IN bookquantity INT
-> )
-> BEGIN
-> INSERT INTO tigrenoble.Post
-> (seller_dce, book_isbn, book_condition, book_price, post_date, book_description, post_type, book_quantity,post_status)
-> VALUES
-> (seller, bookid, bookcondition, bookprice, postdate, bookdescription, posttype, bookquantity,'A');
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 15
 MariaDB [tigrenoble]> END;
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `delimiter`:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE tigrenoble.postBook (
IN seller VARCHAR(7),
IN bookid INT,
IN bookcondition VARCHAR(10),
IN bookprice NUMERIC,
IN posttype CHAR,
IN postdate DATE,
IN bookdescription TEXT,
IN bookquantity INT
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tigrenoble.Post(seller_dce, book_isbn, book_condition, book_price, post_date, book_description, post_type, book_quantity, post_status)
    VALUES(seller, bookid, bookcondition, bookprice, postdate, bookdescription, posttype, bookquantity, 'A');

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```